# Closing popup window from the popup

Tags: javascript, html

I'm opening a window using this javascript:

```
function popitup(url) {
        newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=430,width=780,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');
        if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
        return false;
    }
```

I need to close this popup from the popup window itself using a close button, I tried this but it didn't work:

```
onClick="window.close()"
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you show on jsfiddle ,what you have done so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this putting an anchor tag on the popup

```
 <a href="JavaScript:window.close()">Close</a>
```